# C++ Date Library for parsing and date rules

Tags: library, c++, calendar

I'm looking for a C++ library that has equivalent functionality to Python's `dateutil`. Specifically, I want:

`dateutil.parser.parse`: Given a string that represents a date, convert it to some kind of date object from which I can get seconds since the epoch. `dateutil` can handle diverse strings like "January 1st, 2017", " "2017-01-01 18:00" and "Jan 1 17 7am" - if there's a C++ library that can automatically handle a variety of strings as well, that would be ideal.

`dateutil.rrule` - Generate a list of dates and times from a rule. For instance, in Python I can get 7am every Saturday and Sunday between two dates by writing:

```
dateutil.rrule.rrule(
            dateutil.rrule.DAILY,
            byweekday=(dateutil.rrule.SA, dateutil.rrule.SU),
            dtstart=datetime.datetime.combine(start_date_day, datetime.time(7, 00)),
            until=datetime.datetime.combine(end_date_day, datetime.time(23, 59)))
```

I'm looking for the same ability to generate dates/times between dates with rules like the one above.

Comment: 1. Parsing is one thing, and "date rules" are another. I'm not even sure you need a library for the the sequence of dates/date-times if you use something like `std::iota` and `std::transform`. 2. Can you explain what about the standard library's parsing capabilities is insufficient for you? I recall (although I'm not sure) that it does do some parsing.

Comment: I don't really see how `std::iota` helps. How would you write the `rrule` above with `iota`? It would involve checking the days of week, the the start times, end times, etc., which is what I was hoping an existing library would handle for me

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [boost date time library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/date_time.html) which is very comprehensive, open source, mature and is well documented.

It has a very comprehensive Date time parsing and good Date Calculation support. I am sure you can get it to do your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with the C++11 standard, the standard library includes date and time facilities, accessible with via the [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) header file; these should satisfy your parsing needs:

```
std::tm tm;
std::stringstream ss("Jan 9 2014 12:35:34");
ss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S");
auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&tm));
```

<sub>this answer is based on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21021900/1593077) (on StackOverflow.com).</sub>

Comment: Yeah, so the nice thing about Python dateutil is that I don't have to specify the format string. Parsing with a format string is obviously trivial